# How to make two widgets attached to each other and resizing each other in Qt Creator

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

How to create two widgets(QList or QTab for example) attached to each other and draggable line between them so they can be resized together(one gets bigger and the other smaller and the other way around)?

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsplitter.html
This can be done in the form editor with the layout options (shown below).
[image: Setup the layout with splitters in the form editor]

This will allow you to drag back and forth in between your widgets.

Comment: This option is always disabled for me. I am using the same items.

Comment: QSplitter *splitter = new QSplitter(parent);
    QListWidget *listwidget = new QListWidget;
    QTabWidget *tabwidget = new QTabWidget;
    
    splitter->addWidget(listwidget);
    splitter->addWidget(tabwidget);